# Finding the index position of a 2-dimensional array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am getting a list of strings from a server,

```
let a="18647AF0D0,59,6]1864726D1,65,5]1864726A,85,5]1864726A,75,5]";
```

and with every set of data I am adding a close bracket, which means the set of data is now complete.

So The data look like this

```
mac = "18647AF0D0";
TTL = "59"
TIME = "6"
```

And the server continues to send the data, which is added to the variable `a`

Now This data I need to display on the web server  on a HTML site, which has already been designed.

So The issue is here when the server sends sometime it sends a same mac value with a updated TTL and TIME

```
1864726A,85,5]1864726A,75,5]
```

Here, if you see, I am getting the same mac value, so what I want to do is if the mac value already exists, then just update the TTL and TIME values on the same position; it should not be creating another entry.

So I was trying to store this value into an array using a split function, but it's getting too complicated, so I am stuck here.

Here is my html page :- https://codepen.io/kanxababu/pen/KKeZKQZ

Comment: If your question is about finding an index position, it would be better to provide a minimal example that just focus on this issue. Including the code to split the string is not related to the question and should be left out.

Comment: Sorry Question Updated

Comment: What's the correct answer to the index of '1864726A'?  Is it 6?  Is it  [2,0]? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question quietly
but if you want separate your array with "," and "]" here is the way :

```
const result = a.split("]").join("").split(",")
```

Comment: I don't want to separate it reason I did this my data are coming from server in a string format so every data with a end character "]" so with the help of this I distinguish my 1 set of data .

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, just add it in to your existing code. It'll return an array of the position of the array and the position of the element within that array. I think there's probably a syntactically nicer way to do the if statement but I'm not sure, and it would work the same anyways.

```js
function twoDIndexOf (myArray, element) {
  let index
  for (let i=0;i<myArray.length-1;i++){
    if(myArray[i][0].indexOf(element) != -1) {
      return [i, myArray[i][0].indexOf(element)]
    }
  }
}
console.log(twoDIndexOf(array, '1864726A'));
```